# Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead Template Shows Empty But Only The First Time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

This is weird...the first time I will type in the input box, the typeahead template will pop up but will show empty. But if backspace and do it again...then the template populates. It's like there is some kind of race condition with `typeahead-template-url`. Ater that, the issue goes away until the next page refresh. Any ideas?

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer").controller("BindNodeCtrl", function($scope, $modalInstance, VipService, NodeService, Account, StatusTrackerService) {
  (function(promise) {
    return $scope.getNodeLabel = function(val) {
      return promise.then(function(nodes) {
        var dropDownItems;
        dropDownItems = [];
        _.forEach(nodes, function(node) {
          if (_.str.include(node.id.toLowerCase(), val.toLowerCase())) {
            return dropDownItems.push({
              label: node.label,
              address: node.address,
              port: node.port_number,
              value: node.id,
            });
          }
        });
        return _.sortBy(dropDownItems, 'label');
      });
    };
  })(NodeService.getNodes());
```

---

```
  <input  type="text" id="label" name="label" ng-model="$parent.node.id" typeahead-min-length="1"
               placeholder="Node Name / Label"
               typeahead-editable="false"
               typeahead="dropDownItem as dropDownItem.label for dropDownItem in getNodeLabel($viewValue)"
               typeahead-template-url="typeahead/bind-node.html" style="width:100%;"
               typeahead-loading="loadingNodeLabels" class="form-control" required>
```

---

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="typeahead/bind-node.html">
<a><i>{{match.model.label}} &mdash; {{match.model.address}} &mdash; {{match.model.port}}</i></a>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have just come across this issue today and have discovered that the issue was the script tags around the content in the template file. The script tags are only needed if you are including the template inline. If the template is in an external file, such as yours, the script tags should be removed. I am unsure why they cause the errors with the backspacing, but removing the script tags solved this problem for me. I hope this helps you as well, and maybe someone else can shed some light onto what is going on behind the scenes to make this happen in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me too.